# XmlSec1 signing pksc12 from file does not work after the update anymore

Tags: xmlsec1

Environment: macos, Xmlsec1, current version 1.3.1_1 (homebrew)
I am signing xml file using command:

```
xmlsec1 --sign --pkcs12 cert.p12 --pwd **** --output out.xml tmpl.tmplt
```

Couple days ago it worked fine, but today i am getting an error:

```
Error: xmlSecCryptoAppKeyLoadEx failed: filename='cert.p12'
Error: failed to load pkcs12 key from "cert.p12".
Error: keys manager creation failed
Unknown command
Usage: xmlsec <command> [<options>] [<files>]
```

I quest i got some updates yesterday and something has been changed about security or smth.

I cannot find any info about whats changed.
Maybe someone knows more about that issue and can show me where to search

EDIT: run same command with same files on another mac (same OS) without any errors. It produced the file as expected.